# Why is the partial derivative of this fuction locally bounded?

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative

We have a function for $x_i, t_i >0$

$$|f(x_1,t_1)-f(x_0,t_0)| \leq C (|t_1-t_0|^{1/2} + |x_1-x_0|)$$

Why does this mean $f_t$ is locally bounded?

$f$ is non-increasing and convex in $x$. $f$ is non decreasing in $t$. Also $f$ is bounded below by 0 and above by a constant.

---

We have $$f_t(x,s) = \lim\limits_{u\rightarrow s} \dfrac{|f(x,u) - f(x,s)|}{u-s}$$

The bound only tells us

$$\lim\limits_{u\rightarrow s} \dfrac{|f(x,u) - f(x,s)|}{|u-s|}\leq C|u-s|^{-1/2}$$

Which can blow up.

Comment: Is that $x_2$ up there meant to be an $x_0$?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva yes. thanks

Comment: Why are you sure $f_t$ is locally bounded? I am not convinced either.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva because a paper says so. I will try to see if I missed any conditions.

Comment: Papers can seem wrong if you read them wrong, or sometimes papers can be wrong. You should figure out if something weird is happening in there, I'm trying to think of a counter example ; I don't believe your conditions are sufficient.